# why does stack grows downward?

Tags: linux, overflow, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do stacks typically grow downwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035568/why-do-stacks-typically-grow-downwards)

In most system(linux, windows, etc)
stack starts at high memory address and grows lower.

but, most buffers grows from lower address to higher address.
is there a reason for this?

because I think this is the fundamental problem of
buffer overflow attack.

I've seen that in earlier days, due to some reason, system designers
made stack to grow downwards...

but I see even nowadays, this architecture(different direction of growth of stack and buffer) 
doesn't seem to be changed.

I know there is NX protection, ASLR, stack guard(canary), etc stuffs to
protect buffer overflow attack.  but I don't understand why they dont
make growth direction of buffer and stack same...

am I missing something?

Comment: If you had searched for "why does stack grow downward" in google, you would have found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2035568/912144) as first result!