# Why do we need a stackpointer register when we already have program counter register?

Tags: cpu-registers

I'm confused with it because if we already have a pointer then we can easily point to next instruction, we can easily point to get back previous function so then why we need another stack pointer register to get back to previous function or module?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack pointer used for in microprocessors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464035/what-is-a-stack-pointer-used-for-in-microprocessors)

Answer (score 19):

The program counter tells the CPU where it *is*. The stack is used to (amongst other things) keep a record of where it has *been*.

If a function is called, that function needs to know where to return to once it has finished. This could indeed simply be an address passed in, but if that function itself calls other functions, or even calls itself recursively, then it needs to ensure that this address is not lost or overwritten - so it must be stored. The natural way of doing that, is to push the address onto a stack, and the pop it back off again when needed.

Of course it also stores the local state for a function, because that too needs to be pushed and popped as the program descends into or returns from functions.

Not all processors necessarily have a stack, but if you do anything remotely complex on one, you inevitably implement one.

Answer (score 0):

The program conter keep the position of next instruction, stack pointer point to a pile(stack) where the processor store information for later use, for example the values of internal registers before to jump to a subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

SP is used to retrieve data from the stack register where it stores temporary data like bi-products of any operation or content before power failure to recover it back

whereas PC as u know hold the address of the next instruction to executed..