# Is my analysis of space complexity correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

This is problem 9.5 from Cracking the Coding Interview 5<sup>th</sup> edition

**The Problem:** Write a method to compute all permutations of a string

Here is my solution, coded in Java(test it, it works :) )

```
public static void generatePerm(String s) {
    Queue<Character> poss = new LinkedList<Character>();
    int len = s.length();
    for(int count=0;count<len;count++)
        poss.add(s.charAt(count));
    generateRecurse(poss, len, "");
}
private static void generateRecurse(Queue<Character> possibles, int n, String word) {
    if(n==0)
        System.out.println(word);
    else {
        for(int count=0;count<n;count++) {
            char first = possibles.remove();
            generateRecurse(possibles, n-1, word+first);
            possibles.add(first);
        }
    }
}
```

I agreed with the author that my solution runs in *O(n!)* time complexity because to solve this problem, you have to consider factorials, like for a word like "top", there are three possibilities for the first letter, 2 for the second and so on....

However she didn't make any mention of space complexity. I know that interviewers love to ask you the time and space complexity of your solution. What would the space complexity of this solution be?

My initial guess was O(n<sup>2</sup>) because there are n recursive calls at each level n. So you would add n + n - 1 + n - 2 + n - 3.....+ 1  to get <sup>n(n+1)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> which is in O(n<sup>2</sup>). I reasoned that there are n recursive calls, because you have to backtrack n times at each level and that space complexity is the number of recursive calls your algorithm makes. For example, when considering all the permutations of "TOP", at level, 3 recursive calls, gR([O,P],2,"T"), gR([P,T],2,"O"), gR([T,O],2,"P") are made.    Is my analysis of space complexity correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you got the right answer but for the wrong reason.  The number of recursive calls doesn't have anything to do with it.  When you make a recursive call, it will add a certain amount of space to the stack; but when that call exits, the stack space is released.  So suppose you have something like this:

```
void method(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            method(0);
        }
    }
}

method(1);
```

Although `method` calls itself 10000 times, there will still be no more than 2 invocations of `method` on the stack at any one time.  So the space complexity would be O(1) [constant].

The reason your algorithm has space complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>) is because of the `word` string.  When `n` gets down to 0, there will be `len` stack entries being taken up by invocations of `generateRecurse`.  There will be `len` stack entries at most, so the space usage of the stack will only be O(n); but each of those stack entries has its own `word`, which will all exist on the heap at the same time; and the lengths of those `word` parameters are 1, 2, ..., `len`, which of course *do* add up to `(len * (len+1)) / 2`, which means the space usage will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

**MORE ABOUT STACK FRAMES:** It appears that an explanation of the basics of stack frames would be helpful...

A "stack frame" is just an area of memory that's part of the "stack".  Typically, the stack is a predefined area of memory; the location and size of stack frames, however, are not predefined.  When a program is first executed, there won't be anything on the stack (actually, there will probably be some initial data there, but let's say there's nothing, just to keep things simple).  So the stack area of memory looks like this:

```
bottom of stack                                       top of stack
------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      nothing                                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
^
+--- stack pointer
```

(This assumes that the stack grows upward, from lower to higher addresses.  Many machines have stacks that grow downward.  To simplify, I'll keep assuming that this is a machine whose stack grows upward.)

When a method (function, procedure, subroutine, etc.) is called, a certain area of the stack is allocated.  The area is enough to hold the method's local variables (or references to them), parameters (or references to them), some data so that the program will know where to go back when you `return`, and possibly other information--the other information is highly dependent on the machine, the programming language, and the compiler.  In Java, the first method will be `main`

```
bottom of stack                                       top of stack
------------------------------------------------------------------
| main's frame |                  nothing                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------
                ^
                +--- stack pointer
```

Note that the stack pointer has moved up.  Now `main` calls `method1`.  Since `method1` will return to `main`, the local variables and parameters of `main` have to be preserved for when `main` gets to resume executing.  A new frame, of some size, is allocated on the stack:

```
bottom of stack                                       top of stack
------------------------------------------------------------------
| main's frame | method1's frame |      nothing                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  ^
                                  +--- stack pointer
```

and then `method1` calls `method2`:

```
bottom of stack                                       top of stack
------------------------------------------------------------------
| main's frame | method1's frame | method2's frame |   nothing   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                    ^
                                                    +--- stack pointer
```

Now `method2` returns.  After `method2` returns, its parameters and local variables will no longer be accessible.  Therefore, the entire frame can be thrown out.  This is done by moving the stack pointer back to where it was before.  (The "previous stack pointer" is one of the things saved in some frame.)  The stack goes back to looking like this:

```
bottom of stack                                       top of stack
------------------------------------------------------------------
| main's frame | method1's frame |        nothing                |
------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  ^
                                  +--- stack pointer
```

This means that, at this point, the machine will see the portion of the stack starting with the stack pointer as "unused".  It's not really correct to speak of `method2`'s frame being reused.  You can't really use something that has ceased to exist, and `method2`'s frame no longer exists.  Conceptually, all there is is a big empty area of the stack.  If `method1` calls another method, whether it's `method2`, `method1` recursively, `System.out.println`, or something else, a new frame will be created at the place where the stack pointer is now pointing.  This frame could be smaller, equal, or larger in size than the `method2` frame used to be.  It will take up part or all of the memory where the `method2` frame was.  If it's another call to `method2`, it doesn't matter whether it's called with the same or different parameters.  It can't matter, because the program doesn't remember what parameters were used last time.  All it knows is that the area of memory starting with the stack pointer is empty and available for use.  The program has no idea what frame most recently lived there.  That frame is gone, gone, gone.

If you can follow this, you can see that when computing the space complexity and when looking just at the amount of space used by the stack, the only thing that matters is, how many frames can exist on the stack at any one point in time?  Frames that may have existed in the past but no longer do are not relevant to the computation, no matter what parameters the methods were called with.

(P.S. In case anyone was planning to point out how I'm technically wrong about this or that detail--I already know that this is a gross oversimplification.)

Comment: so 10,000 calls to method(0) will re use the same stack frame over and over again?

Comment: Why did you add up all the lengths? Say with the "TOP" example, the first function call would be generateRecurse([O,P], 2, "T"). Then the next would be generateRecurse([P], 1, "TO"). Finally the last recursive call would be generateRecurse([],0,"TOP"). I agree here that there are len stack frames. However I don't get why you added the lengths of each of the words. Each word is just a local variable. I should have corrected myself. Space complexity is related to the depth of the recursive call. In this case, the depth of the recursive call is len so shouldn't space complexity be O(n)?

Comment: To answer both your comments: (1) yes.  (2) I added the lengths of the words because they all exist in memory at the same time.  They have to.  When the last recursive call exits, it goes back to the second call, where `word` is `"TO"`.  That means that the string `"TO"` has to stay in existence while the last recursive call is running--the program can't reconstruct it out of thin air when it exits.  Similarly, the string `"T"` has to stay in existence while both the other recursive calls are executing....

Comment: ...hopefully you can see that at the point when the stack is at its deepest, all of the strings must be present, taking up memory, and thus the lengths need to be added to determine how much space is taken up.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarifying that :). I have another question about your first example. Say I have two calls f(3), f(4). Would these two function calls reuse the same stack frame even though they are taking different input?

Comment: @committedandroider please see my edit.  The answer to your question is "sort of yes, except that that's not really how things work".

Comment: Thanks for your diagram! A question about the second to last pictorial. In that picture,  is the stack pointer supposed to be pointing at method 2's frame? Based off this definition, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464035/what-is-a-stack-pointer-used-for-in-microprocessors, a stack pointer is the address of the most recent entry that was pushed on top of the stack. I wasn't sure in that picture if the stack pointer was pointing at nothing or at method 2's frame?

Comment: @committedandroider Both that answer and my answer are meant to illustrate the general concepts of how a stack works, and the definitions of the terms shouldn't be taken literally.  Another answer to the same question says "The Stack Pointer is a register which holds the address of the next available spot on the stack", which is more in line with my diagrams.  Neither definition is inherently wrong.  Most processors have a register they call the "stack pointer", and whether the pointer points to the last item pushed, or to the next available address, depends on the processor.