# Why the address of variable become smaller?

Tags: c, memory, memory-address

I thought the memory address of variable become bigger and bigger, until I tried this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()
{
    int IamfirstVariable = 9;
    char array1[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char array2[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char IamLastVariable = '0';
    printf("variable start :%p\n",&IamfirstVariable);
    printf("array1 address start :%p    end :   %p \n",&array1[0],&array1[9]);
    printf("array2 address start :%p    end :   %p \n",&array2[0],&array2[9]);
    printf("variable end :%p\n",&IamLastVariable);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
variable start :0xbfb02c3c
array1 address start :0xbfb02c32    end :   0xbfb02c3b 
array2 address start :0xbfb02c28    end :   0xbfb02c31 
variable end :0xbfb02c27
```

I am stucked by this . It seems that the last declared variable get the smallest address!

Can anyone explain this for me ?

----------------------EDIT----------------------------------------

I read the links in answer and got anohter question:

> Since the stack glow downaward , why the address of array still glow upward ?

Comment: If you are interested, try the heap instead of stack, and see the result.

Comment: @YuHao I tryed , it give me discontinuous but grow upaward memory address.  I can understand this, but I still can't understand the reason stack grow downaward ! Is it only to have a stack limit ?

Comment: Because on many platforms, stack grows downward, while heap grows upward. Try to search the image of stack and heap in memory. A picture is more than any words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because on Intel the stack *grows* downward (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/1691818/613130). Your `array1` and `array2` being local variables are allocated on the stack. Note that this is platform-specific, not C-specific. On different platforms it could *grow* upward.

If you are interested on which architectures have stacks that grow upward or downward, a similar question was already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/664779/613130

Comment: I used a CPU made by AMD

Comment: @LidongGuo Intel == AMD in this case, because they both use the x86/x64 ABI .

Comment: why the array address still grow upward ?

Comment: @LidongGuo Because an array is defined in that way in C, so that `array[x] == *(array + x)`. You see the `+` sign? See for example http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Answer (score 2):

Because variables are stored in the stack.

Stack memory allocation use a very simple algorithm: the stack pointer points the first empty space and is moved down each time you add a variable.

See also: [Understanding the Stack](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)

Comment: The `move down` means move to the smaller address ?

Comment: why the array address still grow upward ?

Answer (score 1):

lets see Empty stack

```
0x00000000   |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |
0xFFFFFFFF   |       | ==>position of stack pointer
            -----------
```

when variable one declared ,Memory to the var1 will be allocated in stack and then stack pointer position comes to up.

```
0x00000000   |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |==>position of stack pointer
0xFFFFFFFF   | var1  |
            -----------
```

when variable two declared ,Memory to the var2 will be allocated in stack and then stack pointer position comes to up.

```
0x00000000   |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |
    :        |       |==>position of stack pointer
    :        | var2  |
0xFFFFFFFF   | var1  |
            -----------
```

so the last declared variable get the least address and first declared variables got max address.