# Modifying return address with a buffer overflow attack

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

So I am trying to modify the return address of this function to make it run forever. I realize that I need to change the return address with the address of the function this way it will loop forever.

Here is the code

```
void win(char * arg)
{

    char name[16];
    char * stuff[4] = {"TV", "Phone", "Car", "Cash"};

    strcpy(name, arg);
    printf("Your name is %s:\n", name);
    printf("Here you can use this to win %s!\n", stuff[rand()%4]);
    printf("Here is the number %d\n\n", rand());
}
```

`arg` is just `argv[1]`

I used gdb to get the address of the win function, which is `0x8048530`. I used the info frame command to look at saved eip (which is return address correct?) at it is `0x804862c`. I believe to get to the return address I need to overflow `name[]`. I am guessing I can some how calculate exactly where I can insert the address of win to overwrite the return function. So something like `name[23]`. `name[0]` address is `0xbffffaa0` `name[16]` address is `0xbffffab0`. The address of arg is `0xbffffac0`. So that is all the information I know. I just am struggling putting it all together to cause the attack. Apparently if I cause name to overflow it will go into stuff, but I need to change the return address so I need to go the other way. How can I do that using a buffer overflow attack

Answer (score 0):

By overflowing `name`, you'll corrupt the local variable that resides after it, `stuff` in this case.
In order to rewrite the return address, you need to go back in the stack, not forward.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward) answer has a nice sketch of stack layout.

Comment: So after looking at the sketch you provided. The return address lies between arg and name[] correct? This kind of confuses me more as how I can cause an buffer overflow attack but have it go backwards