# stack memory layout in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-layout

I try to verify my understand of the stack memory layout in C by compiling following code and inspect the address in gdb. I only record the least significant digits, the higher ones are the same. The outputs are generated by using the

```
print \u &a
```

Here is a simple test code:

```
void test(int a,int b)
{
  int c = a;
  int d = b;
  printf("%d,%d\n",c,d);
}

int main()
{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;
  test(x,y);
  return 0;
}
```

If I look at the test function frame, I have following results,

&b: 6808
&a: 6812

&c: 6824
&d: 6828

$rbp: 6832 (frame pointer).

I am confused. Shouldn't function parameters sit at higher memory address with respect to the local variables. Can someone explain this in detail please?

Edit:
If I print the memory out like:

```
printf("&a:%p,&b:%p\n",(&a),(&b));
printf("&c:%p,&d:%p\n",(&c),(&d));
```

I got

```
&a:0x7fff4737687c,&b:0x7fff47376878
&c:0x7fff47376888,&d:0x7fff4737688c
```

It turns to be in b a c d order. There is a 8 byte gap between end of a and beginning c. I guess it shall be the return address?

Comment: Some stacks grow upward, others downward. Depends on the system.

Comment: Your code and results would make more sense if you actually printed the address of the variable in the code, e.g. `printf("%p, %p\n", &a, &b);` inside `test()`.

Comment: OP appears to be inspecting the addresses in a debugger.

Comment: On x64, parameters are not passed on the stack.

Comment: @RaymondChen ... [unless there are too many to be passed through registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx)

Comment: On which architecture are you working? The stack is different on each one.

Comment: The wikipedia page is actually not that bad. It describes the general case and points out the the actual layout of stack frames is machine dependant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: C does not even require the stack to exist, much less specify its layout.

Answer (score 0):

As per the flow of a function, first arguments are allocated and then the internal arguments.
Your concern is based on the presumption that stack grows upwards (which is not necessary).

Please follow the below link for more understanding:
[Does stack grow upward or downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward)