# Pointer Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

I am trying to learn the concept of pointers in depth. In the below code , I create an array an create a pointer to each of the element.

```
int bucky[5];
int *bp0 = &bucky[0];
int *bp1 = &bucky[1];
int *bp2 = &bucky[2];

cout<<"bp0 is at memory address:"<<bp0<<endl;
cout<<"bp1 is at memory address:"<<bp1<<endl;
cout<<"bp2 is at memory address:"<<bp2<<endl;
```

These are the memory allocations given to the array elements.

> bp0 is at memory address:0x0018ff3c
>   bp1 is at memory address:0x0018ff40
>   bp2 is at memory address:0x0018ff44

With my limited knowledge in c++ , I am aware that memory is allocated contiguously to an array. But looking at the output closely, bp0 looks out of place.

According to me bp0 should be at `0x0018ff36`. Or is it that the locations `0x0018ff3c ,  0x0018ff40  , 0x0018ff44` are continuous in the CPU?

So is it possible that two contiguous memory allocations are not assigned in a progression?

Comment: That’s not how hexadecimal works.

Comment: Yes it is contiguous. If size of pointer is 4 bytes, next pointer will be placed after 4 bytes, isn't it?

Comment: @MohitJain so how does 3c come ? shouldnt it be 46?

Comment: You should not care about memory addresses. `bp0` is the address of `bucky[0]`. `bp0+1` is the address of `bucky[1]` and so on. That's all you need to care. Let the rest to the compiler (they are implementation details) and focus on the logic of your code.

Comment: @axiac just trying to learn something new .

Comment: Why do you think `bp0` should be `0x0018ff36`?

Comment: @axiac: because he thinks in decimal, not in hex.

Comment: @akira I read the question again and I think you are right.

Comment: @axiac see memory is allocated continuously to an array. Now, as every element is an integer , each element occupies 4 bytes of memory. So bp1 is at 0x0018ff40 and bp2 is at 0x0018ff44 which is perfect but how come bp0 is at 0x0018ff3c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does stack grow upward or downward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward)

Comment: @MohitBhasi the `0x` in front of these numbers denotes that they are written using the hexadecimal notation (this is the usual notation of memory addresses). Search for a tutorial about hexadecimal notation and you'll understand.

Comment: Lol is this actually the duplicate of the suggestion question? I dont see the similarity

Comment: This is clearly not a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
           |      bp0      |      bp1      |      bp2      |
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0x0018ff3c   d   e   f  40   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Assuming size of int is 4 bytes and as bp0 points at 0x0018ff3c.

bp1 = bp0 + 4 = 0x0018ff40
bp2 = bp1 + 4 = 0x0018ff44

Comment: ok , thx :) so my interpretation is after 8 there is 9 then there is a then b then c and so on?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is [hexadecimal count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Answer (score 4):

Each int uses 4 bytes.
The first position of the array is 0x0018ff3c so the next int will be at 0x0018ff3c + 4

Notice the addresses are in heaxadecimal, so:

```
0x0018ff3c + 0x00000004 = 0x0018ff40
```

Note: these are all hexadecimal numbers. The order looks like this: `0x3c`, `0x3d`, `0x3e`, `0x3f`, `0x40`, `0x41`...

Comment: Woahhh , had no idea abt it ! can u suggest a place to learn how memory is allocated

Comment: @MohitBhasi: in your 101 cs course, usually. It's not that different from base10, you just have a larger alphabet 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f

Comment: If you are interested in how a computer works at a very basic level, you should start from the begining so your mind doesn't get clogged: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture

This architecture is really old, but the principles are (mostly) the same.