# Stack contraction and expansion

Tags: c++, memory, stack

I want to examine the contraction / expansion of stack based on local variable declarations and a function call. To do so, first I used the following C-style C++ code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MyFunc()
{
    int k = 3;
    printf("%d: %p\n", k, &k);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    printf("%d: %p\n", i, &i);

    int j = 2;
    printf("%d: %p\n", j, &j);

    MyFunc();

    int l = 4;
    printf("%d: %p\n", l, &l);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling using `clang` - `clang -o outputs/Example2.out Example2.cpp` produced the following output -

```
1: 0x7ffd216a8818
2: 0x7ffd216a8814
3: 0x7ffd216a87ec
4: 0x7ffd216a8810
```

Based on the explanation (here)[[Does stack grow upward or downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward]), the output makes sense.
As we allocate the new local variable `j`, the stack address reduces by 0x4. Similarly, when the function is called, there is a bigger reduction in address between outputs 2 and 3. And finally, when the function returns there is an expansion in the address (between 3 and 4).

But, if I use the `iostream` library for outputting the variables and their addresses (and compile using `g++`, I seem to get some discrepancies) -

```
#include <iostream>

void MyFunc()
{
    int k = 3;
    std::cout << k << ": " << &k << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << i << ": " << &i << "\n";

    int j = 2;
    std::cout << j << ": " << &j << "\n";

    MyFunc();

    int l = 4;
    std::cout << l << ": " << &l << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling using - `g++ -Wall -Werror -o outputs/Example.out Example.cpp`, yields the following output -

```
1: 0x7ffda2bb7fdc
2: 0x7ffda2bb7fe0
3: 0x7ffda2bb7fb4
4: 0x7ffda2bb7fe4
```

In this case, we see that the stack expanded by 0x4 from 1 to 2 (i.e. when `j` was declared). However, during the function call, the address contracted (from output 2 to 3 by 0x2c). Based on the answer (here)[[Does stack grow upward or downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward]), I understand that the stack grows either upwards or downwards based on the architecture.
In the first case, the stack contracted during local variable allocation / function call. But here, the stack expands during local variable declaration but contracts during function call.

Is there an explanation to this?

Comment: You will be more surprised if you build your program with enabled optimization.

Comment: All, what you observe, is implementation defined. Don't bother with this, if you're not a developer of compilers. Don't forget about exception handling. Some stuff for it is placed on the stack.

Comment: Even in your 2nd sample, you can see that your stack grows downwards. `3: 0x7ffda2bb7fb4` is still the lowest address of all. I would expect that storage for local variables in `main()` is allocated at once (in both cases). Which local variable uses which address is assigned by the compiler somehow. It seems that the order varies between samples and compilers. But, @S.M. already gave the reason... If in doubt, try your examples on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RQBOTD). The storage for `i`, `j`, and `l` in `main()` is provided in this one line: `31 sub rsp, 16`. ;-)