# Issues on using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I just got started learning about pointers and was executing some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int num = 12;  // initialize num to 12
    int *pnum = NULL;  // initialize the pointer

    pnum = &num;  // stores the address of num in pnum

    printf("the address of the number is %p\n", &num);  // display the address of the number
    printf("the address of the pointer is %p\n", &pnum);  // display the address of the pointer
    printf("the value of the pointer is %p\n", pnum);  // display the value of the pointer
    printf("the value the pointer is pointing to is %d\n", *pnum);  // display the value the pointer is pointing to

    return 0;
}
```

In this code above, It prints out `0xffffcbec` for the address of the number and value of the pointer, and `0xffffcbe0` for the address of the pointer. I want to know the reason. I feel like this is related to some incorrect inputs of data types.

I use VScode btw.

Comment: `I want to know the reason.` The reason for what? Its quite unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The reason it prints 0xffffcbe0 for the address of `pnum` is because the address of `pnum` is 0xffffcbe0.

Comment: pointer is a var himself and so on have a dedicated address where it store the pointed address.

so, 0xffffcbe0 hold your pointer data and his content store 0xffffcbec.

it seem that the linker has stored pointer var before your int in your program memory, all is nice.

Comment: See [Does stack grow upward or downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward)

Answer (score 4):

The value of `pnum` is the value of `&num`, i.e. the location of the variable `num`. Therefore `&num` and `pnum` will print the same.

To make it easier to understand and visualize, I recommend you draw it all out:

```
+-------+      +------+      +-----+
| &pnum | ---> | pnum | ---> | num |
+-------+      +------+      +-----+
```

That is:

- `&pnum` is pointing to `pnum`
- `pnum` (which is the same as `&num`) is pointing to `num`

---

Also, the pointer-to operator `&` and the dereference operator `*` are each others opposites.

So `pnum` is the value of `&num`. And `*pnum` is the value of `num`.

And `*&num` is plain `num`, as the operators cancel out each other.

Comment: I am sorry everyone who confused on my question. I was gonna clarify my question but stackoverflow was crashing at the time. SO, I was wondering, is there nothing wrong with my code? Because I thought it should print 8-bits but 0xffffcbec looks like more than 8-bits( 8-bits means basically 8 characters right?) and I assumed that there was an error. I want to know if the code is how it is supposed to happen.

Comment: @TrevorSong A *bit* is a single `0` or `1`. A *byte* is a collection of (usually) 8 bits. An address on a 32-bit system is 4 bytes, and 8 bytes on a modern 64-bit system. A single hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits.