# Does the stack pointer grow up or down?

Tags: operating-system

Does the stack pointer grow up or down? Espacially in Linux/Unix and Windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664744/what-is-the-direction-of-stack-growth-in-most-modern-systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the platform. On x86 it goes downwards, on ARM processors you can choose.

Answer (score 1):

On the x86, it grows towards lower memory addresses.