# Who selects the ARM stack direction?

Tags: stack, arm

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664744/what-is-the-direction-of-stack-growth-in-most-modern-systems) the ARM stack grow direction is selectible, but who selects this direction exactly? The operating system? The app? The manufacturer?

If it is the operating system, what's the stack direction for iOS, Android and Windows RT?

Comment: ultimately you as a programmer can chose the stack pointer setting, and the stack instructions.  Of course if you are using a compiler you  have to check with the compiler and linker to see if there is a setting, and yes the operating system is going to make assumptions as well.  Just like big endian on arm, an upward growing stack is not the normal/typical case.  I would have to have a really good reason to not go with the flow

Comment: Then iOS, Android and Windows RT expects to be under a 'growing down' stack?

Comment: I have not heard of an upward growing stack application, I dont know the details of those applications.  you could write yourself a get sp function (ldr r0,sp, bx lr) and call from nested functions and see which way it goes

Comment: Read the ARM ABI documents.

Comment: As per *starblue* and *dwelch*, the *selectable* option is not real.  You must write your own compiler with an *upward* growing stack.  At the assembler level, you can have the stack grow either way.  Most people only think there is a single stack.  If you are completely confined to *assembler*, you can use either up/down and even multiple stacks.  In order to make the ARM instructions symmetric, you can pre/post increment or decrement with all registers.  Either direction exists on the *ARM* but for all pragmatic considerations, the **stack grows down**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately it's the designers of the operating system who choose which direction the stack grows in.

If you want to create your own stack, and not rely on the one given to you by the OS, you can use whatever type of stack you choose.  However, if you want to use the OS stack, you have no choice but to accept what the OS gives you.

The first OS that ran on ARM was Arthur, written by Acorn Computers.  Arthur uses a growing-downwards stack, quite possibly because the developers who wrote Arthur were used to the stack on the 6502, which also grows downwards.  (Arthur didn't last long, and was quickly replaced by RISC OS.)

There is a version of ARM Linux that runs on Acorn hardware - I still have a version of it on my 1995 Acorn Risc PC.  I know that that version of the ARM Linux kernel makes calls into RISC OS for various purposes, so it has to use growing-downwards stacks as well.  Other operating system developers quite probably followed the lead set by Acorn and/or the ARMLinux developers.

As for iOS, it appears to use a growing-downwards stack (the [`STMFD` instructions here](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=82) suggest that).  I suspect the same is true for Android and Windows RT, but I haven't been able to verify this.

Comment: It defined by the [APCS](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/teaching/2001-02/arm-project/02-sort/apcs.txt); in fact the *compiler* and *libc* determines this more than the OS.  For an OS that uses an *mmu* to manage user memory, it shouldn't care if the user stack grows up or down.  Most of the time, the OS takes parameters in registers.  I am not aware of any *OS* that cares about the stack direction.

Comment: Traditionally, stacks generally grow downwards, whilst heaps group upwards, ideally never meeting in the middle.  Stacks on modern operating systems are always contiguous, so if placed at an arbitrary location, they would be limited if they grew upwards by the virtual memory space available between that point and the upper limit of addressable memory.   These days with multi-threaded applications. stacks have to have a finite limit - as each thread stack is able to grow.  Typically this limit is a few MB.

Comment: @Luke Woodward: I seem to recall that RISCOS actually supported non-contiguous stacks and software stack limit checking. That is to say, the compiler emitted code in function prologues to check that the stack limit wasn't about to be breached and called the C runtime library for another stack chunk if it was.  This worked because `r13` was always stored in the stack-frame and would be reloaded in the function epilogue.