# Why isn't my loop working correctly in c?

Tags: c

This is my code. It is supposed to first of all scan 2 number m and n. Then scan an array of numbers that is x[n]. Number of scanned numbers in second line should be n. But it doesn't work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int x[n];
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0 ;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }
}
```

It just scans 1 number and breaks out of the loop. We should have (i)s from 0 until n-1;

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf()` after reading user input. If the user entered something other than numbers, your `scanf()`s will have returned 0 *and not have written anything to their argument variables*.

Comment: Because you have declared `int n = 0;` and immediately `int x[n];` which gets translated to `int x[0];` which is equivalent to `int x;`. Your code is actually scanning all the numbers and is storing it in `int x[n]` but at the end of the loop, the last number is getting stored and all other numbers are getting overwritten

Comment: This is a FAQ, see [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n = 0;
int x[n];
```

This attempts to declare a Variable Length Array of size zero, which already is undefined behaviour.

And even if that (having a VLA with room for zero elements) were somehow possible,

```
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);
```

...would also be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain the behavior of the code considering `x86_64` architecture and `gcc7.5x` compiler.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/664753/2805824) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/664779/2805824) to the questions provides the direction of stack growth on different architectures for `x86` it is downward, meaning the stack will grow from high memory to low memory address (0xFF --> 0x00)

If we slightly modify your code to print the addresses and values of the variable during runtime as shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int x[n];
    
    printf("Size of int: %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("Address of\nm: %p\nn: %p\nx: %p\n", &m, &n, &x);
    printf("Enter a value of m: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter a value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        printf("Addr: %p\n", &x[i]);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("x[%d]: %d\n", x[j]);
    }
    printf("m: %d n: %d\n", m, n);
}
```

After compiling and running the above code on `x86`, we can notice that the addresses to the local variables get assigned in decreasing order as shown below for one of the code execution session:

```
Address of
m: 0x7ffdfb2b1704
n: 0x7ffdfb2b1700
x: 0x7ffdfb2b16f0
```

If you notice the difference in the address of `n` and `x`, they are `16-Bytes` apart, ideally they should have been `4-bytes` apart on stack.
But as `int x[n]` is declared to be an array of 0 integers ideally it should occupy 4-bytes of memory, even though the underlying compiler and architecture mechanism is treating it as an array of 4 integers, which gets translated to
`4 integers * sizof(int) = 16-bytes`

Looking at further execution output of the code, we can see that the value of `n` at address `0x7ffdfb2b1700` gets overwritten as the code executes further.

> Note that the code will work properly for values of `n < 5`, because for the value of `n = 4` the loop will terminate at `n = 3` in which case the value of `n` will not get overwritten because of loop iteration as `(n * sizeof(int)) ==> 3 * 4 = 12-bytes`:

```
Enter a value of m: 1
Enter a value of n: 10
1
Addr: 0x7ffdfb2b16f0
2
Addr: 0x7ffdfb2b16f4
3
Addr: 0x7ffdfb2b16f8
4
Addr: 0x7ffdfb2b16fc
5
Addr: 0x7ffdfb2b1700  <--- address of variable `n` getting overwritten with new value
x[1]: 0
x[2]: 1
x[3]: 2
x[4]: 3
x[5]: 4
m: 1 n: 5
```

And this is the reason why @DevSolar answered that this will result in an undefined behavior.

I hope I was able to provide some clarification.

Comment: I am of two minds about "explaining" undefined behavior. For the most part it's an exercise in futility, since you must not **rely** on that knowledge, ever. Hence I tend to reserve such discussions for "among the experienced", like when discussing potential exploits, and not delve into "what happens on CPU X with compiler Y under setting Z" as an answer to a beginner question.